# Check everything in one list again another, causing a stack overflow

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

Basically, I'm trying to check an arrayList of numbers against another ArrayList of numbers, As I want to see if anything in my TempPositionList, is in my Visited words list, however because Visisted words list maybe smaller, or larger than the temp list, I get stack overflow exceptions.

How may I get around this problem?

```
private void Checker(AdapterView<?> arg0, List<Integer> TempPositionList, boolean checked) {
    if (checked) {
        // its a word
        for (int i = 0; i < TempPositionList.size(); i++) {
            VisitedWords.add(TempPositionList.get(i));
        }

    } else {
        boolean check = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < TempPositionList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TempPositionList.size(); j++) {
                if (VisitedWords.size() > 0) {
                    if (TempPositionList.get(i).equals(VisitedWords.get(j))) {
                        check = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!check) {
                arg0.getChildAt(TempPositionList.get(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your nested `for` loop (the `j` one) probably should be checking against `VisitedWords.size()`, not `TempPositionList.size()`.

Comment: Which in turn would render the `if (VisitedWords.size() > 0)` redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you are attempting to achieve:

```
for (Integer tempInt : TempPositionList) {
    if (!VisitedWords.contains(tempInt)) {
        arg0.getChildAt(tempInt).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

The `contains()` method saves you having to iterate over the second list, and using a `foreach` loop is slightly easier to read in my opinion, it saves you explicitly worrying about the size of the list.

Comment: This code is fantastic, good job man. It fixed my bug that I had , as well as the overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better if you use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check that an object is in the visitedwords. This way you will avoid using two for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the elements which are common in both the lists you can do it this way.

```
tempPositionList.retainAll(VisitedWords);
```

Only the common elements will be retained in tempPositionList after the execution of this statement.